# Functionnal analysis: Why $\langle AAx,x\rangle\underset{(*)}{\leq} (\|A\|+m)\langle Ax,x\rangle-\|A\|m ?$

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products

Let $(X,\langle\cdot ,\cdot \rangle)$ an inner vector space and $A\in \mathcal L(X)$ symetric such that $A\geq 0$.

I set $m=\inf\{\langle Ax,x\rangle \mid x\in X, \|x\|=1\}$ and thus $A-mI\geq 0$. If $\|x\|=1$, we have that

$$\mathbb R\ni\langle (A-mI)Ax,x\rangle\leq \|A\|\langle (A-mI)x,x\rangle=\|A\|\langle Ax,x\rangle-\|A\|m$$
and 
$$\|Ax\|^2=\langle AAx,x\rangle\underset{(*)}{\leq} (\|A\|+m)\langle Ax,x\rangle-\|A\|m.$$

I don't understand were $(*)$ come from. Notice: $\|A\|=\sup\{\|Ax\|\mid x\in X, \|x\|\leq 1\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$\langle (A-mI)Ax,x\rangle=\langle AAx,x\rangle-m\langle Ax,x\rangle,$$

so

$$\langle AAx,x\rangle-m\langle Ax,x\rangle \leq \|A\|\langle Ax,x\rangle-\|A\|m.$$

Since $\langle AAx,x\rangle = \|Ax\|^2$, because $A$ is symmetric, we have

$$ \|Ax\|^2-m\langle Ax,x\rangle \leq \|A\|\langle Ax,x\rangle-\|A\|m$$

then

$$ \|Ax\|^2 \leq (\|A\|+m)\langle Ax,x\rangle-\|A\|m.$$

Comment: Nice :-) Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: How do you conclude the second line from the first one? I.e. Your  "So".

Comment: **@OmranKouba:** The proof of **Irddo** is perfectly correct ! The fact that $\langle AAx,x\rangle\leq \|A\|\langle Ax,x\rangle$ is a consequence of Reid inequality.

Comment: @idm If this were correct then it would imply that $A$ is positive which is not in your assumptions.!

Comment: You right, I forgot to precise it. It corrected it. Thank you :-)

Comment: @idm, Well the conclusion is correct even if $A$ is not positive.

Comment: **@OmranKouba:** Thanks for all your comment, I really appreciate your interest :-) You are probably right, but since I'm using Reid formula, (and this formula is valid only if $A\geq 0$), I have to precise it :-) Thanks for everything,

Comment: could the downvoter explain why he downvoted ?

Comment: I'm sorry for my absence. Thanks you for all correction about my solution.